# Display dictionary contents in a label in python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, dictionary, tkinter

Ive been trying for a while now but i cant seem to display the contents of a dictionary in a label. I want to hit the display button and when i do, i want all the contents in my dictionary to display, see the code below:

```
 import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from datetime import datetime
now= datetime.now()
x = []
d = dict()
def quit():
    print("Have a great day! Goodbye :)")
    sys.exit(0)
def display():
    for key in d.keys():
        x.append(key)
def add(*args): 
    global stock
    global d
    stock = stock_Entry.get()
    Quantity = Quantity_Entry.get()
    if stock not in d:
        d[stock] = Quantity
    else:
        d[stock] += Quantity




root = Tk()
root.title("Homework 5 216020088")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="6 6 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="you are accesing this on day %s of month %s of %s" % (now.day,now.month,now.year)+" at exactly %s:%s:%s" % (now.hour,now.minute,now.second), foreground="yellow", background="Black").grid(column=0, row = 0)

stock_Entry= ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable="stock")
stock_Entry.grid(column=0, row = 1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the stock name").grid(column=1, row = 1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

Quantity_Entry= ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable="Quantity")
Quantity_Entry.grid(column=0, row = 2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the quantity").grid(column=1, row = 2, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Add", command=add).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Display", command=display).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=S)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit", command=quit).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text= x).grid(column=0, row= 4, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Label(..., text= x)` will display only once - at the start.

You have to use `StringVar` to do what you expect

```
x_var = StringVar()
Label(..., texvariable=x_var)
```

Now you can set value in `x_var` to automatically set new text in `Label`

```
x_var.set( x )
```

---

BTW: instead of

```
for key in d.keys():
    x.append(key)
```

probably you should do

```
x = list(d.keys())
```

or maybe even

```
x = list(d)
```

---

**EDIT:** display all keys (as in your code) when you press button "Display"

```
import sys

from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import time
from datetime import datetime

# --- functions ----

def quit():
    print("Have a great day! Goodbye :)")
    sys.exit(0)

def display():
    x_var.set( list(d) )

def add(*args): 
    global stock
    global d
    stock = stock_Entry.get()
    Quantity = Quantity_Entry.get()
    if stock not in d:
        d[stock] = Quantity
    else:
        d[stock] += Quantity

# --- main ---

x = list()
d = dict()

now = datetime.now()

root = Tk()
root.title("Homework 5 216020088")

x_var = StringVar()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="6 6 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="you are accesing this on day %s of month %s of %s" % (now.day,now.month,now.year)+" at exactly %s:%s:%s" % (now.hour,now.minute,now.second), foreground="yellow", background="Black").grid(column=0, row = 0)

stock_Entry= ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable="stock")
stock_Entry.grid(column=0, row = 1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the stock name").grid(column=1, row = 1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

Quantity_Entry= ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable="Quantity")
Quantity_Entry.grid(column=0, row = 2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the quantity").grid(column=1, row = 2, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Add", command=add).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Display", command=display).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=S)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit", command=quit).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=x_var).grid(column=0, row= 4, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import ttk
import time
from datetime import datetime


# --- functions ----

def quits():
    print("Have a great day! Goodbye :)")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()


def display():
    x_var.set(list(d))


def add():
    global d
    stock = stock_Entry.get()
    quantity = Quantity_Entry.get()
    if stock not in d:
        d[stock] = quantity
    else:
        d[stock] += quantity


# --- main ---

x = list()
d = dict()

now = datetime.now()

root = Tk()
root.title("Homework 5 216020088")

x_var = StringVar()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="6 6 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="you are accessing this on day %s of month %s of %s" % (
now.day, now.month, now.year) + " at exactly %s:%s:%s" % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second), foreground="yellow", background="Black").grid(column=0, row=0)

stock_Entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=60, textvariable="stock")
stock_Entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the stock name").grid(column=1, row=1, 
    sticky=(N, W, E, S))

Quantity_Entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=60, textvariable="Quantity")
Quantity_Entry.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Please enter the quantity").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky= 
    (N, W, E, S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Add", command=add).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Display", command=display).grid(column=0, row=3, 
    sticky=S)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit", command=quits).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=x_var).grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add explanation of the code please.

Comment: The (*args) in the function (add()) was removed, as it was not used anywhere in the code. The variable global stock was also removed. The sys module also was removed. The time module was used instead to exit the program. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: first: you should describe it in answer's body, not in comments. second: these changes doesn't add something special - you only copy my answer without adding importing modifications. And this is why I downvote it.